# XML file accessible from XAML and code behind

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wpf, xaml

Is it possible to have an XML file embedded in the project that can be accessed from code behind and directly from XAML using XMLDataProvider?

When I set the XML file as "Embedded Resource", I can access it from code, but not from XAML.
When I set the XML file as "Resource", I can access it from XAML, but not from code.

Now it is possible to load a Resource from using a Pack Uri from code, however the xml file is in a 'service' library and I don't feel like referencing PresentationFramework, WindowBase, etc. to make this work.

External XML file is also not an option since a lot of unit tests will break. The solution would be to add an attribute to those tests, only there are A LOT.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily set xml files are Resource and then read them in code as follows

```
        Uri uri = new Uri("/file.xml", UriKind.Relative);
        StreamResourceInfo info = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);
        if (info != null)
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(info.Stream))
            {
                string xml = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
```

Here file.xml is Resource so replace to whatever name you have

Comment: Only thing is that StreamResourceInfo is in PresentationFramework. In a service library there should be no need to reference it...

Comment: Any assembly can read its own resources as well using GetManifestResourceStream(), so if its some general library without any WPF in it then use that. Look msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc4235zt(v=vs.110).aspx